# NodeJS v.0.10.X is not backwards compatible with v0.8.X for multicast

Tags: node.js, bind, multicast, multicastsocket

NodeJS v.0.10.X is not backwards compatible with v0.8.X for multicast.

`bind` seems to have changed from synchronous to async.

I'm currently working around the issue with a horrible fudge:

https://github.com/chrisdew/multicast-eventemitter/blob/master/lib/multicast-eventemitter.js#L87

Is there a mistake in how I'm using the API, or is backwards compatibility broken here?

If I use the v0.10.X code with NodeJS v0.8.X I get no messages being received (I assume the call to 'bind' is synchronous here, and doesn't call the function provided.

If I use the v0.8.X code with NodeJS v0.10.X I get an error:

```
dgram.js:354
    throw errnoException(process._errno, 'setMulticastTTL');
          ^
Error: setMulticastTTL EBADF
    at errnoException (dgram.js:439:11)
    at Socket.setMulticastTTL (dgram.js:354:11)
    at MulticastEventEmitter.addListener (/home/chris/Dropbox/multicast-eventemitter/lib/multicast-eventemitter.js:96:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chris/Dropbox/multicast-eventemitter/examples/loopback.js:17:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

Can anyone see a way to remove this horrendous fudge?

Comment: I've also submitted this as a bug: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5446

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is no longer synchronous. You can check the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html) too.

> Important note: the behavior of dgram.Socket#bind() has changed in
>   v0.10 and is always asynchronous now.

If you have code that looks like this:

```
var s = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
s.bind(1234);
s.addMembership('224.0.0.114');
```

You have to change it to this:

```
var s = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
s.bind(1234, function() {
  s.addMembership('224.0.0.114');
});
```

It will be like this so you would have to change your code.

Comment: I have changed my code.  What I don't like is having a horrible version number check condition in my code.  I'm trying to find a solution to this.

Comment: I don't think you have an option here. Doing version check/depending on non-major version is a bad idea indeed. As per docs it will always be asynchronous now, so you must use the new API.